# Cento's 2 network and 2 ip work only 1

Tags: centos, network-interface

Hi I have configiured 2 network card

eth0:

```
TYPE=Ethernet
PROXY_METHOD=none
BROWSER_ONLY=no
BOOTPROTO=none
DEFROUTE=yes
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6INIT=yes
IPV6_AUTOCONF=yes
IPV6_DEFROUTE=yes
IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6_ADDR_GEN_MODE=stable-privacy
NAME=eth0
UUID=7fxxxxx
DEVICE=eth0
ONBOOT=yes
ETHTOOL_OPTS="autoneg on"
IPADDR=192.168.1.10 (example IP... my ip is public)
PREFIX=32
GATEWAY=192.168.1.254
DNS1=8.8.8.8
DNS2=8.8.4.4
IPV6_PRIVACY=no
ZONE=
```

eth1:

```
TYPE=Ethernet
PROXY_METHOD=none
BROWSER_ONLY=no
BOOTPROTO=none
DEFROUTE=yes
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6INIT=yes
IPV6_AUTOCONF=yes
IPV6_DEFROUTE=yes
IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6_ADDR_GEN_MODE=stable-privacy
NAME=eth1
DEVICE=eth1
ONBOOT=yes
ETHTOOL_OPTS="autoneg on"
IPADDR=192.168.1.12 (example IP... my ip is public)
UUID=7fxxxxy
GATEWAY=192.168.1.254
DNS1=8.8.8.8
DNS2=8.8.4.4
IPV6_PRIVACY=no
ZONE=
```

outside I ping eth0 and not eth1, if I put offline eth0 I can ping eth1.. why?

Answer (score 0):

A Linux server can only have one default gateway and the first (eth0) is taking precedence.

Supposing the different IP addresses are on different Internet providers/networks, it means the ping answers to eth1 will go via the upstream of the first provider (eth0).

So ultimately, if the first provider is doing it's job (1), and filters  out in the *their* upstream IP source IP addresses which do not belong to the corresponding ISP provider, the answer never arrives.

See a related question on our sister site SuperUser [How to route only specific subnet (source ip) to a particular interface?](https://superuser.com/questions/376667/how-to-route-only-specific-subnet-source-ip-to-a-particular-interface)

(1) Some ISPs do, some do not. Nowadays, more do than in the past. When I managed an ISP I did filter out all IP address space in my upstream which did not belong to us, and oddly enough, a customer and a competitor/client managed to open tickets complaining they could not (ab)use our upstream to route foreign/**their** IP netblocks.

Comment: More precisely, a Linux server can have only one **default** gateway.

Comment: @JohanMyréen Indeed, thanks for remembering it!

Comment: My problem is that for Italy domain I need 2 ns and to my server to ovh I have purchased 2 ip to set ns and ns1 also the check dns resolve not confirm the domain grrrrr

Comment: @StefanoCoccia I would advise using two separate VMs.

Answer (score 0):

resolved...
to navigate from 2 ip at the same subnet and 1 GW

https://serverfault.com/questions/885006/how-do-i-set-up-routing-for-a-second-network-interface-in-the-same-subnet